# Load image to panel

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I created a folder "images" inside my project.
When the function SetImage() is called, i want to take the image from /images/image.jpg and place it on my Panel.
The panel declaration on xaml looks like this:

```
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration"
xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"

            <my:WindowsFormsHost Name="windowsFormsHost1">
                <wf:Panel x:Name="panelWinform"  Dock="Fill" />
            </my:WindowsFormsHost>
```

Example that works ti display a control in the panel:

```
panelWinform.Controls.Clear();
panelWinform.Controls.Add(controlObject);
controlObject.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
```

How can place the picture instead of the controlObject?
And what does the .clear() does? Do I need to call it again?

Comment: Why do you use _System.Windows.Forms_ ???

Comment: it is a given code. in addition to answer if you can provide better solution/recommendation it will be great. thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be very easy *without*  WinForms. You might have a Grid or some other Panel:

```
<Grid x:Name="panel">
</Grid>
```

and simply add an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms610982.aspx) control to the Panel as shown below.

```
public void SetImage()
{
    var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/image.png");
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage(uri);
    var image = new Image { Source = bitmap };

    panel.Children.Add(image);
}
```

---

The image URI looks like that because I assume that the image file is a resource in your Visual Studio project. See [Pack URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) for some details. You may as well use an absolute or relative file path for the URI.

Comment: There are both WinForms ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx)) and WPF panel ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx))

Comment: But it is of course a [WPF Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx)-derived class here, like Grid or Canvas.